# Manually optimize a nested loop

Tags: c, optimization

I'm working on a homework assignment where I must manually optimize a nested loop (my program will be compiled with optimizations disabled).  The goal of the assignment is to run the entire program in less than 6 seconds (extra credit for less than 4.5 seconds).

I'm only allowed to change a small block of code, and the starting point is such:

```
    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }
```

Where `ARRAY_SIZE` is 9973.  This loop is contained within another loop that is run 200,000 times.  This particular version runs in 16 seconds.

What I've done so far is change the implementation to unroll the loop and use pointers as my iterator:

(These declarations are not looped over 200,000 times)

```
 register int unroll_length = 16;
 register int *unroll_end = array + (ARRAY_SIZE - (ARRAY_SIZE % unroll_length));
 register int *end = array + (ARRAY_SIZE -1);
 register int *curr_end;

curr_end = end;

while (unroll_end != curr_end) {
 sum += *curr_end;
 curr_end--;
}

do {
 sum += *curr_end + *(curr_end-1) + *(curr_end-2) + *(curr_end-3) +
  *(curr_end-4) + *(curr_end-5) + *(curr_end-6) + *(curr_end-7) +
  *(curr_end-8) + *(curr_end-9) + *(curr_end-10) + *(curr_end-11) +
  *(curr_end-12) + *(curr_end-13) + *(curr_end-14) + *(curr_end-15);
}
while ((curr_end -=  unroll_length) != array);

sum += *curr_end;
```

Using these techniques, I was able to get the execution down to 5.5 seconds, which will give me full credit.  However; I sure do want to earn the extra credit, but I'm also curious what additional optimizations I can make that I might be overlooking?

Edit #1 (Adding outer loop)

```
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
  x = rand() / (int)(((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1) / 14);
  array[j] = x;
  checksum += x;
 }

 for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

  // inner loop goes here

  if (sum != checksum)
   printf("Checksum error!\n");

  sum = 0;

 }
```

Comment: Does the array being summed change each time? It would be helpful to see the outer loop too.

Comment: The array does not change.  I've added the outer loop to the question.

Comment: are you allowed to unroll the number generation loop as well? Also, what happens if you unroll the loop more than 10 times (say, 20)?

Comment: Do it in steps of 4 or 8. Try to see if sub-sums would help. Look at the generated assembly, debug versions do like to write back values to the stack just to present better debugger feedback.

Comment: I wouldn't use powers of ten on a computer, they tend to prefer powers of two (unrolling by 10 seems weird to me, I would have done either 8 or 16).

Comment: I am _not_ allowed to modify the number generation or the outer loop.  When I did the initial unroll to 5 times, my execution went from 16s to 8s.  From 5 to 10 went to 6s, then the pointer iteration shaved off another 1s.  I don't think unrolling to 15 or 20 would save me sufficient time to win the extra credit.

Comment: Pre-compute stuff you can: (ARRAY_SIZE - (ARRAY_SIZE % 10)), modulo could be costly.

Comment: @jv42 That all depends on instruction & data latencies though.

Comment: Are you allowed to use inline assembly?

Comment: @Wayne, yes.  In fact, another student says he used inline assembly and got it down to 1.2s.  I was hoping to avoid going that deep.

Comment: …and, of course, [Duff’s device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) is useful for unrolling inner loops.

Comment: Since you're allowed to use inline assembly, what compiler and architecture are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to store your variables in CPU register with :

```
register int *unroll_limit = array + (ARRAY_SIZE - (ARRAY_SIZE % 10));
register int *end = array + ARRAY_SIZE;
register int *curr;
```

and try with different size of manual loops to check when you maximize cache usage.

Comment: Most compilers ignore the register keyword.

Comment: @Jasper:  Since the assignment grade is apparently based on running with one specific compiler on one specific system, it's worth a try.  It may work or it may not, but it's not going to hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're on x86, if you're not most of this will still apply but the details differ.

1. Use SIMD/SSE, this will get you a 4x speed increase without much effort, it needs 16-byte aligned data that you can get with `_aligned_malloc` or regular `malloc` + manual alignment. Besides that all you'll need in this case is `_mm_add_epi32` to do four additions at the same time. (Different architectures have different SIMD units so check yours).
2. Use multi-threading/ multiple cores in this case it'd be easiest to have each thread sum half the array to a temporary variable and sum those two results when done. This will scale linearly across the number of cores available.
3. Prefetch to L1 cache; this only works when you've got a huge array and are sure to be able to stress the CPU for at least ~200 cycles (eg. a roundtrip to main RAM).
4. Completely go out of your way to optimize the hell out of it and use a GPU based approach. This will require you to set up a CUDA or OpenCL environment and upload the array to the GPU. This is about ~400 LoC excluding the compute kernel. But might not be worth it if you have a small dataset (eg. too much overhead in setting up/tearing down) or if you have a *huge* changing dataset (eg. too much time spend in streaming to the GPU).
5. Align to page boundaries to prevent page-faults (expensive) on windows these are usually 4K in size.
6. Manually unroll the loop while taking into account dual issuing instructions and instruction latencies. This information is available from your CPU manufacturer (Intel provides these too). But on x86 this isn't really useful because of it's CPUs out of order execution.
7. Depending on your platform actually getting the data to the CPU for processing is the slowest part (this is mainly true for recent consoles & PS, I've never developed for small embedded devices) so you'll want to optimize for that. Tricks like iterating backwards are nice on a 6502 when cycles were the bottleneck but these days you'll want to access RAM linearly.
8. If you do happen to be on a machine with fast RAM (eg. NOT PC/Consoles), converting from the plain array to a more fancy data-structure (eg. one that does more pointer chasing) might totally be worth it.

All in all, I guess that 1 & 2 are easiest and most feasible and will gain you more than enough performance (eg. 8x on a Core 2 Duo). However, it all comes down to knowing your hardware and programming PIC will require completely different optimizations (eg. instruction level manual pipelining) than a general PC will.

Comment: Nice advice, although you should realistically be able to get a nicely optimized reduce program in about 120loc (with comments and blank lines) in cuda. And I know that because writing a reduce function is probably the first thing everyone does with cuda ;)

Comment: @Voo I did a raytracer, but yeah It's closer to a 120loc than 400 for the setup part. Guess I'll edit that. http://code.google.com/p/basic-opencl-raytracer/

Answer (score 1):

- Try to align the array on a page boundary ( i.e. 4K )
- Try to compute with a wider data type, i.e. 64 bit- instead of 32-bit integers. This way you can add 2 numbers at once. As the final step add up the both halves.
- Convert part of the array or the computation to floating point, so you can use FPU and CPU in parallel
- I don't expect the following suggestions to be allowed but I  mention them anyway

  - Multithreading
  - Specialized CPU-Instructions, i.e. SSE

Comment: +1 for the second advice (sum using a larger type, then fold the sum)

Comment: (Incidentally, TCP/IP csums are usually calculated used 32/64 bit arithmetic, then the result is folded).

Answer (score 0):

If the array values don't change, you could memoize the sum (i.e. calculate it on first run, and use the calculated sum on subsequent runs).

Answer (score -1):

Some nice optimization tricks:

- make your loop count backwards from ARRAY_SIZE to 0 so that way you can remove the comparisons from your code. Less comparisons speed up the program.
- Furthermore x86 nowadays are optimized for short loops which they can "preload" to run faster then normal.
- Try to use registers wherever possible
- Use pointers instead of array indices

So if you would use arrays, try to use:

```
register int idx = ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
register int sum = 0;
do {
    sum += array[idx];
} while (idx-- % 10 != 0);

do {
    sum += array[idx] + array[idx - 1] + array[idx - 2] + array[idx - 3] + array[idx - 4] + array[idx - 5] + array[idx - 6] + array[idx - 7] + array[idx - 8] + array[idx - 9];
} while (idx -= 10);
// now we don't use a comparison and the ZERO flag will be set in FLAG
// register on which we can conditional jump. With a comparison you do VALUE - VALUE
// and then check if the ZERO flag is set or the NEGATIVE flag or whatever you are testing on
```

Comment: You could also use `array[idx--] + array[idx--] + array[idx--]` etc and replace the `idx -= 10` by `idx` to remove 449 bogus calculations.

Comment: You cannot decrement the same variable several times in one expression. That leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also when you would surround all items with parentheses? Then you would need to do some more typing and place them all on a separate line :) Also you would need to place an last `sum += array[idx]` after the last loop to add the first element.