# Memoization of Simple Arithmetic for loop

Tags: c++, memoization

While reading another interesting [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952636/manually-optimize-a-nested-loop) regarding `for` loop optimization, I noticed one of the commentors suggested using `memoization` technique.

I dug around a bit to learn more and found several examples of how to memoize functions such as [factorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/kdason/archive/2013/07/25/loops-recursion-and-memoization-in-javascript.aspx) or [fibonacci](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/) sequence just to name two.

I can follow these and understand the general idea but I'm struggling with how this can be applied to a simple arithmetic operation such as the one in the original post:

```
for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
    sum += array[j];
}
```

What would be the portion that has already been calculated?

Is it possible or was the commentor incorrect on their assumption that it could apply here?

---

Just interested in learning `memoization` techniques in this post, I know there are other methods such as unrolling, that provide significant optimization.

Comment: The commentor was probably referencing the fact that the code you quoted is run by an outer loop 200,000 times. If that results in duplications of `array`, memoization would optimize it quite a bit.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ You confirmed my suspicion and since no one else has posted a counter argument I'll give you credit.  Please post an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I added it. Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That for-loop can't be memoized in itself. [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is applicable when you can store previously solved subproblems and use them to calculate bigger subproblems/problems. It's therefore closely related to functions that can be solved by recursion since this also means that a problem is split into subproblems. (See also: [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)).